# Populate A Form By Cycling Through An Array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to populate a form with an id of 'amenduser' by cycling through a JSON result set produced by a php query.

The form has 15 fields so it's not such an issue to address each form element in jquery using $('#amenduser input[name="id"]).val(data.id); etc etc.

To make the code more user friendly (and portable) I have tried to cycle through the JSON data as follows:

```
for (var key in userDetails) {
    var elem = '#amenduser input[name="' + key + '"]';
    $(elem).val(userDetails.key);
    console.log(key, elem);
}
```

This code doesn't work!
A sample of the console log:

```
username #amenduser input[name="username"]
```

The element id appears to me to be formed correctly but no joy.

I would be grateful for any ideas as I've spent hours on this so far.

Roger

Comment: i think the problem could be at $(elem).val(userDetails.key) try out: userDetails[key]

Comment: Sorted! Thanks for your input - I got hung up on the JSON addressing element and never thought to try this.

Comment: Great :) i'll put it as an answer then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think the problem could be at `$(elem).val(userDetails.key)` try out: `userDetails[key]`